# checkbox group don't work - codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter and need work with checkbox group. In view:

```
<fieldset>
    <input type="checkbox" id="country" name="country[]" value="Cat" />Cats <br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="country" name="country[]" value="Dog" />Dogs<br />
</fieldset>
```

In controller:

```
foreach ($this->input->post('country') as $country)
{
    echo $country;
};
```

When i'm check or not check - It always `echo "";`

Comment: Give some more codes. Your supplied code does not contains any error. Give the full form and controller function.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<fieldset>
    <input type="checkbox" id="country" name="country" value="Cat" />Cats <br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="country" name="country" value="Dog" />Dogs<br />    
</fieldset>
```